How can I close and open a new window?
I try to close and open a windows using PyQt5 and the following code:
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys
import os

class Window2(qtw.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    uic.loadUi("window2.ui",self)

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    uic.loadUi("selectWindow.ui",self)
    self.path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
    self.pbStart.clicked.connect(self.showData)    
    
  def showData(self):
      print(self.leInput.text())  
      self.w = Window2()
      self.w.show()
      self.hide()      

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv) 
  win = MainWindow()
  win.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

The first windows appears, I can enter some value and press the button, but then I get the following error:
$ python selectWindow.py
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DEV\Fiverr2024\TRY\artfulrooms\selectWindow.py", line 20, in showData
    self.w = Window2()
             ^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DEV\Fiverr2024\TRY\artfulrooms\selectWindow.py", line 9, in __init__
    uic.loadUi("window2.ui",self)
  File "D:\DEV\.venv\pyqt\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\__init__.py", line 241, in loadUi
    return DynamicUILoader(package).loadUi(uifile, baseinstance, resource_suffix)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DEV\.venv\pyqt\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\Loader\loader.py", line 66, in loadUi
    return self.parse(filename, resource_suffix)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DEV\.venv\pyqt\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 1037, in parse
    actor(elem)
  File "D:\DEV\.venv\pyqt\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 822, in createUserInterface
    self.toplevelWidget = self.createToplevelWidget(cname, wname)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DEV\.venv\pyqt\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\Loader\loader.py", line 57, in createToplevelWidget
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: ('Wrong base class of toplevel widget', (<class '__main__.Window2'>, 'QDialog'))

How can I close the actual windows and open the new window2?

The error message is self-explanatory. Just change to class Window2(qtw.QDialog). You could also easily find a solution to this minor issue by doing a web-search on the error message.

I made a dummy project for you to see how it works:
from PyQt6 import QtGui, QtCore , QtWidgets
import sys
 
 
class Window2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window2, self).__init__(parent)
        
    
 
class Window1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("click me")
 
        self.setCentralWidget(self.pushButton)
 
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)
        
 
    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        dialog = Window2(self)
        dialog.closeEvent = lambda event:self.show()
        dialog.show()
        self.hide()
 
 
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Window1()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

You can change this as you wish
dialog.closeEvent = lambda event:self.show()

This is for opening window1 when window2 closed, so if you need do more action after window2 closed like saving some data in database
Just change it like
dialog.closeEvent = self.yourfunc

and add def yourfunc(self,event) to your code like this
    def showWindow1(self,event):
        self.show()
 
    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        dialog = Window2(self)
        dialog.closeEvent = self.showWindow1
        dialog.show()
        self.hide()

